# Как эффективно подсчитать количество атрибут, при XSLT преобразовании

Tags: xml, xslt

Подскажите начинающему программисту. есть исходный XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
 <DATA>
  <file NN="1" CAT="WZ2" ARH="5" />
  <file NN="2" CAT="WM1" ARH="5" />
  <file NN="3" CAT="WM2" ARH="4" />
  <file NN="4" CAT="WM1" ARH="6" />
  <file NN="5" CAT="WM2" ARH="5" />
  <file NN="6" CAT="WM2" ARH="5" />
  <file NN="7" CAT="WZ2" ARH="6" />
  <file NN="8" CAT="WZ1" ARH="4" />
  <file NN="9" CAT="WZ2" ARH="4" />
  <file NN="10" CAT="WZ2" ARH="6" />
  <file NN="11" CAT="WZ1" ARH="6" />
  <file NN="12" CAT="WZ2" ARH="4" />
  <file NN="13" CAT="WZ2" ARH="4" />
  <file NN="14" CAT="WZ2" ARH="6" />
  <file NN="15" CAT="WZ2" ARH="5" />
  <file NN="16" CAT="WM1" ARH="6" />
  <file NN="17" CAT="WZ2" ARH="5" />
  <file NN="18" CAT="WZ2" ARH="6" />
  <file NN="19" CAT="WZ2" ARH="6" />
  <file NN="20" CAT="WM1" ARH="4" />
 </DATA>
```

необходимо преобразовать в

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SVEDENIYA>
  <GLAVA>
   <ARH>4</ARH>
   <ALL_ARH>6</ALL_ARH>
   <WZ1>1</WZ1>
   <WZ2>3</WZ2>
   <WM1>1</WM1>
   <WM2>1</WM2>
  </GLAVA>
  <GLAVA>
   <ARH>5</ARH>
   <ALL_ARH>6</ALL_ARH>
   <WZ1>0</WZ1>
   <WZ2>3</WZ2>
   <WM1>1</WM1>
   <WM2>2</WM2>
  </GLAVA>
  <GLAVA>
   <ARH>6</ARH>
   <ALL_ARH>8</ALL_ARH>
   <WZ1>1</WZ1>
   <WZ2>5</WZ2>
   <WM1>2</WM1>
   <WM2>0</WM2>
  </GLAVA>
</SVEDENIYA>
```

используя условия:

```
    ALL_ARH - общее количество arh 
    WZ1 - количество arh и wz1 
    WZ2 - количество arh и wz2 
    WM1 - количество arh и wm1 
    WM2 - количество arh и wm2
```

самым простым и не правильным способом у меня получилось так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="DATA">
    <SVEDENIYA>
        <GLAVA>
          <ARH>4</ARH>
          <ALL_ARH><xsl:value-of select="count(file[@ARH = '4']/@ARH)"/>    </ALL_ARH>
          <WZ1><xsl:value-of select="count(file[@ARH = '4'][@CAT = 'WZ1']/@ARH)"/></WZ1>
          <WZ2><xsl:value-of select="count(file[@ARH = '4'][@CAT = 'WZ2']/@ARH)"/></WZ2>
          <WM1><xsl:value-of select="count(file[@ARH = '4'][@CAT = 'WM1']/@ARH)"/></WM1>
          <WM2><xsl:value-of select="count(file[@ARH = '4'][@CAT = 'WM2']/@ARH)"/></WM2>
        </GLAVA>
         ...
         ...
    </SVEDENIYA>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Как более рационально использовать адресацию xpath - не указывать явным образом атрибут ARH и объединить все вычисления в один блок, при помощи функцию key без переменных?

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно использовать группировку. А если вначале вытащить все файлы одной главы в переменную, то работать будет гораздо шустрее.

```xml
<xsl:template match="DATA">
  <SVEDENIYA>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="file" />
  </SVEDENIYA>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="file">
  <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::file[@ARH = current()/@ARH])">
    <GLAVA>
      <ARCH>
        <xsl:value-of select="@ARH" />
      </ARCH>
      <xsl:variable name="arch" select="../file[@ARH = current()/@ARH]" />
      <ALL_ARH>
        <xsl:value-of select="count($arch)" />
      </ALL_ARH>
      <WZ1>
        <xsl:value-of select="count($arch[@CAT = 'WZ1'])" />
      </WZ1>
      <WZ2>
        <xsl:value-of select="count($arch[@CAT = 'WZ1'])" />
      </WZ2>
      <WM1>
        <xsl:value-of select="count($arch[@CAT = 'WZ1'])" />
      </WM1>
      <WM2>
        <xsl:value-of select="count($arch[@CAT = 'WZ1'])" />
      </WM2>
    </GLAVA>
  </xsl:if>
<xsl:template>
```

Если не важен порядок тегов `<WXX>` то можно еще подсократить

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с ключами.

XSLT 1.0.

```
<xsl:key name="arh" match="file" use="@ARH"/>

<xsl:template match="DATA">
    <SVEDENIYA>
        <xsl:for-each select="file/@ARH[generate-id() = generate-id(key('arh',.)/@ARH)]">
            <xsl:sort/>
            <GLAVA>
                <ARH> <xsl:value-of select="."/> </ARH>
                <ALL_ARH> <xsl:value-of select="count(key('arh',.))"/> </ALL_ARH>
                <WZ1> <xsl:value-of select="count(key('arh',.)[@CAT = 'WZ1'])"/> </WZ1>
                <WZ2> <xsl:value-of select="count(key('arh',.)[@CAT = 'WZ2'])"/> </WZ2>
                <WM1> <xsl:value-of select="count(key('arh',.)[@CAT = 'WM1'])"/> </WM1>
                <WM2> <xsl:value-of select="count(key('arh',.)[@CAT = 'WM2'])"/> </WM2>
            </GLAVA>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </SVEDENIYA>
</xsl:template>
```